# PHP: Process multiple textboxes with numbers at each end

Tags: php, dynamic-programming

I know how to process something like: 
`<input type="text" name="Textbox_T[]" id="txBox1" />`

but I have an unknown number of boxes (they are generated via javascript and are only known to me after they are submitted) that are named like this:

`<input type="text" name="Textbox_T1" id="txBox1" />`

Textbox_T1
Textbox_T2
Textbox_T3
Textbox_T4
etc

since I cannot do: 
`$_GET['Textbox_T'.$i]`

how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the textbox name to an array:

```
<input type="text" name="textboxes[]" />
<input type="text" name="textboxes[]" />
<input type="text" name="textboxes[]" />
<input type="text" name="textboxes[]" />
```

and then in the code

```
if (is_array($_GET["textboxes"])){
   foreach ($_GET["textboxes"] AS $value){
      echo $value." entered in a textbox.<br />";    
   }
}
```

---

edit: If you can not change the name, you could iterate over ALL 
GEt-values:

```
foreach ($_GET AS $key=>$value){
   if (strpos($key, "Textbox") === 0){
      echo $value." has been entered in textbox ".$key."<br />";
   }
}
```

Comment: Better to check if it's an array beforehand.

Comment: I can't change how I get the textboxes... I can only process them as they come in...  
As I said in the beginning "I know how to process..", its the way they come in now that has me puzzled

Comment: Worked perfectly for my needs, thanks, will choose it as the answer as my time runs out :)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'd have the javascript add the textareas to submit as an array:

```
<textarea name="Textbox_T[]" ></textarea>
```

(I'm assuming you're talking about textareas) because then you just need to loop through that item in PHP once it's been submitted:

```
foreach($_GET['Textbox_T'] as $text){
   //... do something
}
```

However, if you're stuck with it, you can just loop through your submitted _GET array and attempt to match based on a substring:

```
$prefix = "Textbox_T";
foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
   if (substr($key,0,strlen($prefix))==$prefix){
     //this is one of them! do something
   }
}
```